# How to find out on which port mongo is?

Tags: mongodb

I know that default mongo port is `27017` and I can connect to this instance on such port.

But I tried to figure it out by other means.

I found that `mongo` is running by `ps aux | grep mongo` with it I can see `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

At `/etc/mongod.conf` port is `27018`

Netstat `netstat -tulnp | grep 2701` gives me

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27018           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I don't know why I don't see name of the process. Is there any other way to be sure that mongo works on `27017`?

Comment: You can launch gnome system monitor and see what is the pid (say 12345) of mongo. Then, you can use this command: ps -aux | grep 12345

Comment: Did you run `netstat` as root?

Comment: @muru no, should it be root?

Comment: @viakondratiuk if you want to see the processes, yes. It will warn you: `Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.`

Answer (score 9):

```
lsof -i | grep mongo
```

This will list all open files (`lsof`) that are listening on "Internet addresses" (`-i`).  The output of this is piped to `grep`, which is used to filter by text.  In this case, we're looking for all files open, related to the Internet, that match the word **mongo**.

Comment: That will work only if there is already a client accessing to the database. I may suggest start "mongostat" for example on a different terminal and let it run while executing lsof -n -i | grep mongo (-n is faster because it does not try to resolve names)

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can use:

```
lsof -i -ac mongod
```

lsof can do more than just look up network connections. the "-a" is for "And" so it will have to match both criteria. Otherwise it defaults to "Or". The "-c" is for the command. You can also specify user name or PID or lots of other stuff.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `nmap` to scan ports in range from 1 to 65535 with `-p-` flag

For instance,

```
Downloads:$ nmap -p- localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-10 12:07 MST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00036s latency).
Not shown: 65529 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
631/tcp   open  ipp
37818/tcp open  unknown
46400/tcp open  unknown
```

Comment: `nmap -p 27017 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @earthmeLon why 27017 ?

Comment: Just providing a complete example.  I interpreted he doesn't want to scan all ports. Just a comment in case he didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

From the system shell you can use `lsof` or `netstat -an` as you mentioned to view what a process is doing in terms of open ports.  As an alternative you can run the [`db.getCmdLineOpts()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/) command from the `mongo` shell.  That output will give you all the arguments passed on the command line (argv) to the server and the ones from the config file (parsed) and you can infer the ports `mongod` is listening based on that information.  Here's an example:

```
{
        "argv" : [
               "/usr/bin/mongod",
               "--config",
               "/etc/mongod.conf",
               "--fork"
        ],
        "parsed" : {
               "bind_ip" : "127.0.0.1",
               "config" : "/etc/mongodb/mongodb.conf",
               "dbpath" : "/srv/mongodb",
               "fork" : true,
               "logappend" : "true",
               "logpath" : "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log",
               "quiet" : "true",
               "port" : 30001
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

If you have not passed specific port options like the one above, then the `mongod` will be listening on 27017 (normal) and 28017 ([http status interface](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-status-interface)) by default.

**Note:** there are a couple of other arguments that can alter ports without being explicit, see here:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#sharding.clusterRole

I mention this because your `lsof` output also shows port 27018 open, which is the default if you have the `shardsvr` option set.  Hence, your output suggests that you may have a `mongos` on 27017 and a (shard) `mongod` on 27018.  If you connect to each and run the `getCmdLineOpts()` you should be able to figure out how things are configured.